# How to avoid repeating similar properties for all tds of a table in a wordpress post

Tags: css, html, table

Consider the following table.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: right; direction: ltr;">1</td>
<td style="text-align: right; direction: ltr;">2</td>
<td style="text-align: right; direction: ltr;">3</td>
.
.
.
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: right; direction: ltr;">1</td>
<td style="text-align: right; direction: ltr;">2</td>
<td style="text-align: right; direction: ltr;">3</td>
.
.
.
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What can I do to avoid repeating the same properties for the all the tds. Is it possible to do so without using the css file? The problem I am facing is, in a wordpress post, one cannot use the `<head> or <style>` tags.

Comment: Why "without using the CSS file"?

Comment: Because the table is specific to only a certain post, so the style could be better restricted to that particular content.

Comment: Nah, you'll still be better off using classnames & adding the styles to your CSS. Plus it keeps your options open if you do in fact need to add another table elsewhere in the future.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds logical, thanks. But, for my own information, there's no way to include the style in Wordpress posts, at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...there's no way to include the style in Wordpress posts, at all?

You need to add the `style` tag to the list of allowed post tags, and also ensure TinyMCE recognises it in the editor:

```
function wpse_180472_wp_kses_allowed_html( $tags, $context ) {
    if ( $context === 'post' )
        $tags['style'] = array();

    return $tags;
}

add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'wpse_180472_wp_kses_allowed_html', 10, 2 );

function wpse_180472_tiny_mce_before_init( $init ) {
    if ( isset( $init['extended_valid_elements'] ) )
        $init['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',style';
    else
        $init['extended_valid_elements'] = 'style';

    return $init;
}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse_180472_tiny_mce_before_init' );
```